# Ошибка при запуске проекта на Python с aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу бота в телеграм на python с библиотекой aiogram. На одном пк код полностью работает, но на другом пишет, что таких библиотек нет. Какие библиотеки надо установить, что бы все импорты работали?

```
import aiogram.types.input_media_photo
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F
import asyncio
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import sqlite3
import traceback
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup,InlineKeyboardButton,InlineKeyboardMarkup,KeyboardButton, InputMediaPhoto
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup
```

установлены библиотеки:

```
aiogram
asyncio
time
datetime
pytz
sqlite3
traceback
```

Ошибки в строках:

```
import aiogram.types.input_media_photo #всё подчёркивает
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, F #подчёркивает F
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext #всё подчёркивает
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup #всё подчёркивает
```

Comment: Очевидно установить aiogram

Comment: aiogram установлен, но при pycharm подчеркивает строку import aiogram.types.input_media_photo красным

Comment: Так у вас проблема с pycharm или с запуском? Это как бы разные вещи

Comment: проблема с запуском кода, pycharm говорит, что input_media_photo не существует, хотя тот же pycharm той же версии, но на другом пк спокойно запускает код

Comment: наверняка дело в том, что у вас установлена aiogram версии 2.x, а модули вы пытаетесь импортировать от версии 3.x, вот и получаете подчеркивание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы явно установили *не ту* версию [aiogram](/questions/tagged/aiogram). Из-за этого у вас подчёркиваются импорты, потому что в ранних версиях таких подбиблиотек нет. Для решения проблемы впишите в терминал `pip install aiogram -U`.